# How can tracerouting a 192.168.x.x exit the local network?

Tags: networking

In a LAN if I traceroute the IP address of any other machine, it gets it in one hop <1 ms.

However, there is one machine, which if I traceroute, it exits the private network, goes out through external IP adresses, until it stops because of a timeout.

A mail server runs on that machine and it's working properly, if this information is of any help.

What can be the cause of such a strange behavior?

```
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway   Schnittstelle  Anzahl
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.10   192.168.1.148       20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.148   192.168.1.148       20
    192.168.1.148  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.148   192.168.1.148       20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0    192.168.1.148   192.168.1.148       20
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.148   192.168.1.148       1
Standardgateway:      192.168.1.10
```

Comment: Please show us `traceroute` output and routing table of host from which you're tracerouting.

Comment: I don't quite understand it. Is that information really absolutely necessary to answer the question? I was expecting something like `it is completely normal and can happen due to <short explanation>` or `something like this shouldn't normally happen`. Please tell me why such personal information is necessary, like my MAC Adress, or my network provider (which is visible in the `tracert` output) and such my current location, external IP Adress, etc. I can, however, post the route list of my routing table if you find it useful.

Comment: You can replace personal info with `xxx`. Commands output may lit a little light on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Due to the routing it falls back to the default route, unless 192.168.x.x is 192.168.1.x - there is a specific route only for the 192.168.1

Anything else (i.e. 192.168.5.6) will go via default route and that may leave the network. Any non-stupid admin will filter those IP addresses on the gateway router, for security reasons.

Comment: SOHO-grade CPE often doesn't have those filtering capabilities.

Comment: Accepted answer. And I'm an idiot because of not thinking of this possibility. (I'm not an admin, just a curious user)

Comment: @Alnitak and that is how relevant? I mean "soho grade CPE" are something that people talk on SuperUser - not where things are done in a professional capacity (serverfault) ;)

Comment: @TomTom there's professional, and there's using RFC 1918 space and not knowing how routing works...

Comment: @Alnitak no, you mentioned SOHO grade CPE. No professional will use that in a network. A professional will know for example MIkrotik CPE that are dead cheap and can do quite everything.

Comment: That's kinda my point.  I was trying to make a distinction between professional network managers (which is the true target audience for this site) and people who happen to have to run the hardware on their site, in a "professional capacity".  Many, many, companies just have the latter, and they typically use low-grade SOHO CPE.  Those folks wouldn't have the foggiest idea about ingress and egress filtering.

Comment: @Alnitak Should we move this to SuperUser then? I got my answer I was looking for, I just don't know where would this information best benefit future readers.

Comment: No, it belongs here.

Answer (score 4):

A traceroute (and indeed any other packet) *should* only leave the local network if the address in question is not *in the local network*.

If the destination address is in the same subnet as your machine's own interface then the system should use ARP to determine the relevant MAC address, and then send the packet there directly.

Your routing table output shows you are using 192.168.1.0/24 on your local LAN.  Is the address in question perhaps on some *other* portion of 192.168.0.0/16 ?

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility might be a site2site VPN...

tsg